# Module.exports and require confusion

Tags: node.js, oauth, requirejs

I am taking Stephen Grinders MERN course on Udemy. There are three files in the course. My understanding of node modules is that it runs independently, which is why we need to import everything that the module needs inside the module. My question is:

Why is it that in authRoutes.js file we do not need to import the passport.js file? We are using passport.authenticate function is authRoutes.js file it is not configured in the module.

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
require('./services/passport')
const app = express();

require('./Routes/authRoutes')(app);


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

**passport.js**

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const keys=require('../config/keys')

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy(
    {
    clientID:keys.googleClientID,
    clientSecret:keys.googleClientSecret,
    callbackURL:'/auth/google/callback'
},(accessToken,refreshToken,profile,done)=>{
    console.log(`${accessToken}, ${refreshToken}, ${profile.displayName}`)
}
));
```

and

**authRoutes.js**

```
const passport = require('passport');

module.exports=app=>{
    app.get('/auth/google',passport.authenticate('google',{
        scope:['profile','email']
    }))

    app.get('/auth/google/callback',passport.authenticate('google'))

}
```

Comment: But it looks like you *are* importing it already, right? `const passport = require('passport');` Without that, `passport.authenticate` wouldn't work, but you do have it, so it does work?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.Yes this code is working. I am not taking about the node's passport.js module. I am taking about the passport.js module which is the setup file where we implement the passport google authentication

Answer (score 0):

*passport.js* configures Passport, it's necessary to do that before Passport will be used. *passport.js* is imported in *index.js*, before *authRoutes.js* and before Passport is actually used there.

> Why is it that in authRoutes.js file we do not need to import the passport.js file?

This would be needed if *passport.js* was exporting something that *authRoutes.js* needs. But it doesn't export anything, just makes changes to `passport` package internal state - which is same in *passport.js* and *authRoutes.js* .

> My understanding of node modules is that it runs independently, which is why we need to import everything that the module needs inside the module.

This is done to set up a hierarchy of module dependencies. Since it's *authRoutes.js* that actually depends on Passport, it would possibly be more reasonable to import *passport.js* there and not in *index.js*.

Comment: I am having a bit more confusion on this line from your explanation
_This would be needed if passport.js was exporting something that authRoutes.js needs. But it doesn't export anything_

The **authRoute.js** file is using the google strategy as it contains
`passport.authenticate('google')`. However, all of the setup code including `clientID`, `clientSecret` etc lies in the **passport.js** module. How does **authRoutes.js** file get the setup that is in a different module?

Comment: This is what just makes changes to passport package internal state part is about. `passport` is used in both modules. `passport` is same in both modules because JS modules are evaluated once and cached. It 'remembers' that it was configured with Google strategy earlier, if this explanation is more meaningful.